# Disable message when you make a call in the cmd?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

With the `cmd.exe`, i call a programm that I have not write myself. I cannot modify it. I would like to disable the message printed in the shell by this programm.

My OS is Windows 7 enterprise 32 bits.

Thank you

Comment: Which operating system and version do you use?

Comment: `command > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 enterprise 32 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's outputting to standard error and output, you should be just able to redirect them:

```
dodgy_prog >nul: 2>nul:
```

(or use `/dev/null` under UNIXy operating systems - it's unclear which variant you want since you talk about the Windows `cmd.exe` but your question is tagged `bash`).

Comment: I tip:
'C:\>call apital32 >nul: 2>null'
and I become this message:
'Access is denied.'

Comment: @White, you're missing the device designator `:` off the second `null:`.

Comment: Thank!
If i have argument in my function. I have to let >nul: 2>nul: at the end?

Comment: @White, I don't think it's necessary but I've always considered it a good idea.

Comment: Last question: I try to do the same with a programm witch write in a file. He cannot write into the file anymore

Comment: @White, if it's writing to a file by opening the file in the program, that's not standard output, it's a different handle. So no problem.